# is it possible to Python decode base64 string to Solana Transaction Object?

Tags: javascript, python, solana

This is how it is done in JS:

```
const obj = Transaction.from(Buffer.from(base64string, 'base64'));
```

this is how I think it could be done in Python:

```
import base64

base64string = "<some jibberish>"
decode = base64.b64decode(code)
```

it produces a byte type thus far.  I'm not sure if I'm on the right track here...  I've tried using picke.loads to no avail.

Comment: It all seems normal so far. The purpose of base64 is to encode bytes in ASCII, it makes sense that a decode would go to bytes. Next question would be what those bytes are supposed to represent.

Comment: those bytes are supposed to represent a Solana Transaction object

Comment: https://michaelhly.github.io/solana-py/core/transaction/#solana.transaction.Transaction.deserialize